# Probability that one value from one exponential is smaller than the value from another

Tags: probability, exponential-function

I have two exponential (Y1 time between incoming data, Y2 representing the time of cooldown) with $λ_1 = 0.05$ and $λ_2 = 0.5$. I'm trying to find the percentage of data that will be ignored because it'll arrive during the cooldown. So, I want to find the probability that $Y1 < Y2$ (time between 2 data is smaller than the cooldown time).

Edit for clarification: Both are independant exponentials but part of the same system. They basically represent a system where **the mean time between data arrival is 20ns** (exponential Y1) and **the mean processing time of the data is 2ns** (Exponential Y2). If the data arrive while the previous one is processing it'll be ignored. We are interested in the percentage of data that will be ignored. So the percentage of data that has a time between data arrival that is less than the processing time.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Are these assumed independent?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Yes. Both are independant exponentials but part of the same system. They basically represent a system where the mean time between data arrival is 20ns and the mean processing time of the data 2ns. If the data arrive while the previous one is procesing it'll be ignored. We are interested in the percentage of data that will be ignored. So the percentage of data that has a time between data arrival that is less than the processing time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we assume independence:
$$P(Y_1<Y_2)=\mathbb{E}_{Y_2}[P(Y_1<Y_2|Y_2)]=\int_{[0,\infty)}P(Y_1<y|Y_2=y)f_{Y_2}(y)dy=$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^y\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}dx\right)\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2 y}dy=\int_0^\infty\left(1-e^{-\lambda_1 y}\right)\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2 y}dy=$$
$$=1-\int_0^{\infty}\lambda_2e^{-y(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}dy=1-\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$$

Comment: Last line is incorrect: Should be $1-\int\limits_0^{\infty}...dy=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$.

Comment: Yes, correcting it

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of the sum of independent random variables can be obtained as the convolution of the distribution of the individual random variables.
For each $k=1,2$, the variable $Y_k$ has a density function $f_k(x)=\lambda_k e^{-\lambda_k x}$ for $x\ge 0$.  Let $W=-Y_1$ so its pdf is $f_W(x)=\lambda_1 e^{\lambda_1 x}$ for $x\le 0$.  Let $Z=Y_2-Y_1=Y_2+W$.  The pdf for $Z$ is$f_Z(z)=\lambda_1\lambda_2\int\limits_{max(0,z)}^\infty e^{-\lambda_2x}e^{\lambda_1(z-x)}dx$.  Since  only $z\ge 0$ is of interest, we get for this.  $f_Z(z)=\frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}e^{-z\lambda_2}$  The desired result is $\int\limits_0^{\infty}f_Z(z)dz=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$